# Run Wifi (Intel AX210) with Single Antenna

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, wifi-configuration, wifi-driver, wpa-supplicant

Is it possible to run an Intel AX210 chip using a single antenna?  I've got an embedded project where a single antenna would be optimal.  With a single antenna, I get almost perfect data connectivity, but the connection is failing because, I think, the chip is only sending Wifi Beacons out of one antenna at a time, and it isn't always the one I'm using!

The device connecting to it is repeatedly disconnecting due to beacon loss in a single-antenna configuration.

I'm assuming that this is some artifact of MIMO.  Is there any way to disable MIMO on these devices?  I'm on Linux using the iwlwifi driver, but I'm not seeing any option to disable MIMO, either in the driver parameters or in the wpa_supplicant config file.  I'm running Linux 5.15.32.

**UPDATE** - It was suggested that I cross-post this in Electrical Engineering SE.  This post is [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/674011/run-wifi-intel-ax210-with-single-antenna).

Comment: If you connect the other antenna does it work as expected? If you switch which antenna you use does it work.

Comment: This might better be asked at https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: @Ramhound - yes, it appears to work as expected when adding the second antenna.  It does not seem to matter the particular antenna used.

Comment: So it works when you use the unused antenna. So is this device a BT and WiFi card by chance?

Comment: @Ramhound - yes it is a BT/WiFi card.